# Objective C - EXC_BAD_ACCESS on [NSArray count] but can't see how

Tags: objective-c, crash, nsarray, exc-bad-access

I'm working on a piece of code that GETs a URL and parses the contents for data between a asset of tags.  In this case, it's looking for the code between  and .  When the URL body returned doesn't contain those tags, the cullXML: method returns an empty array like this:

```
return [NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
```

I check to be sure that the returned array has objects with:

```
        if ( matchesXML.count ) {
```

In my debug code, I check twice.  The first time, it works fine.  The second time, just a couple lines later, it crashes.  I can't see why.  The lines look the same to me.

What am I missing?

A bigger chunk of the code is included below.  Thanks!

```
   if (self.newResults) {
        NSString *urlResult;
        NSArray *matchesXML;
        NSArray *match;
        NSDictionary *currentResult;
        NSMutableDictionary *results = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSArray *returnedObjects;
        NSArray *dictionaryKeys;
        NSMutableArray *currentResultObjects;

        int i = 0;

        // determine tournament type, because the fields are different per type
        NSString *tournamentType;
        tournamentType = [[AFMethods tournamentTypeFromId:self.inputTournamentId] objectAtIndex:0];

        urlResult = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", responseHandle];
        [responseHandle release];

        NSLog(@"urlResult retrieved: %@", urlResult);
        matchesXML = [AFMethods cullXML: urlResult forTag: @"matches"];

        NSLog(@"matches loaded: %@", matchesXML);
        NSLog(@"matchesXML.count %i", matchesXML.count);
        if ( matchesXML.count ) {
            NSLog(@"not nil");
        } 
        NSLog(@"just before tested");
        if ( matchesXML.count ) {
            NSLog(@"tested");
```

Comment: The logs are:2012-02-06 21:05:08.062 Quartz Composer[3841:407] urlResult retrieved: 

There are no matches completed for this tournament.
2012-02-06 21:05:08.062 Quartz Composer[3841:407] matches loaded: (
)
2012-02-06 21:05:08.062 Quartz Composer[3841:407] matchesXML.count 0
2012-02-06 21:05:08.062 Quartz Composer[3841:407] just before tested

Comment: So is it printing out "not nil" or not?

Comment: I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the next to the last line, just before NSLog(@"tested"); and that NSLog line never gets executed.

Comment: ARC or not?  Printing "not nil" or not?

Comment: Since his code has calls to `release`, and I have to assume he's posting code that compiles, that means it definitely is *not* ARC

Comment: no ARC. Printing "not nil", just like 5 lines up from the bottom.

Comment: Turn on zombies and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue!

It wasn't crashing where I thought.  It was a couple lines later.  I was releasing an auto-released object.  It must have been a left-over line from a previous organization of the code.

I removed the release and it's working perfectly again.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you're not using the return statement you listed, but rather one that returns a different NSArray, only this one isn't retained.  The first NSLog causes heap to be used, stomping on the array object.

Comment: I added another object to the returned array, just to be sure that was the array I was returning.  I did see the log 'matchesXML.count 1' indicating that it was the right array getting returned.